# When is it needed to fuse IMU sensor data with GPS-RTK, and when is it not?

Tags: gps, accelerometer, sensors, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I'm using a high accuracy GPS RTK setup to precisely locate a mobile robotic platform in the field (down to 10 cm accuracy). I have also a 9DOF IMU mounted on the platform (9DOF sparkfun IMU Razor).

The Question is, Do I really need to perform a sensor fusion between IMU and GPS like what this ROS node do (http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to estimate the robot pose? or is it just enough to read the Pitch,Yaw,Rotation data from the IMU to know the heading along with the GPS Long,Lat,Alt ?

What cases make it essential to perform this type of fusion ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is essential to perform fusion because:

1) Roll, Pitch, and Rotation data from the IMU are not perfect, and they will drift over time due to gyro errors.  The magnetic field sensor in the IMU module limits this, but crudely.  Fusion allows the GPS RTK measurements to be used to continuously estimate the dominant error sources in the IMU and maintain better attitude information.

2) The IMU supports position estimation when GPS-RTK is lost through signal blockage or any other outage, such that the robotic platform is not lost when and if GPS signals are interrupted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. the GPS-RTK system I'm using is a single antenna one which means we don't have information about the heading or other orientation directly from the GPS receivers. for this case I think we don't have several sources to fuse between for Roll, Pitch and rotation.. Please advice

Comment: Yes - nevertheless Kalman filter's can derive information about sensor errors from a single antenna receiver.  A  pitch error, for example, will be integrated up from the IMU to produce a vertical velocity error.  The vertical velocity error is observed with GPS.  The correction is applied to the gyro bias via the correlation coefficient in the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix.